# Could load a file or assembly "Renci.SshNet.dll"

Tags: c#

Issue :

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Renci.SshNet, Version=2014.4.6.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=1cee9f8bde3db106' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

The Project is built on .Net Framework 4 which helps to transfer the files from local onto S FTP Server.

The Code works fine on my local machine without any issue,When deployed on the PROD server and run as per scheduled giving the error as mentioned above.

Let me know what exactly causing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If not installing from the gallery make sure the DLL is not marked as blocked. Windows will mark the zip and every file in it for security reasons and you will have to unblock them

Comment: -I build the Project successfully

Comment: I added the build dll onto Server to get it triggered as per Scheduler ,Once dll is executed the error is getting generated

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/590787/what-does-it-mean-when-a-file-is-blocked-in-windows

Comment: The Files are not blocked within the Zip Folder,I verified it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you developing windows or web application? If web application, try enabling an option in IIS application pool -> Advanced Settings, "Enable 32 bit application" to true. This might solve your problem.

In case of windows or console application, select the reference Renci.SshNet dll and go to its properties and set "Specific version" to false.

Comment: Its web application and Renci.SshNet.dll 2014.4.6.0 is used had references.

Comment: How enabling the 32 bit application = true  on IIS solve the problem

Comment: Check if the dll is placed in the bin folder and ensure you have the  assembly reference entry in your web.config file

Comment: The dll is placed in the folder and scheduled to run as required by Task Schedule,the config details are grabbed from db so no web.Config file

Comment: **Scheduled to run?** What exactly are you trying to achieve? Do you want to push files from your local folder into a SFTP folder? If this is what you need, why would you want to develop a web application? A simple Console application or a windows server can serve the purpose.

Comment: The Project  creates folder and files,zip folder within it (it has the Web references) to get it created on Server and using Upload functionality of Renci.SshNet to push the Zip Folder created on the server to SFTP.

Answer (score 0):

After recently upgrading my .NET connector it gave the same error.  I compile and run my app in VS and it works fine guessing because it copies all the MySQL NET assemblies to the exe folder so what I did is copied Renci.SshNet.dll to the directory of my exe and it worked.  For some reason adding the path to the path system variable didn't help.  Final solution was to remove the NET Connector and use mysqld in batch to do the selects and updates for the app.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing the Renci.SshNet.dll.

In your project references you can edit the properties of Renci.SshNet. Make sure "Copy Local" ist set to *true*. It will copy the dll on build to your output directory (should be bin/Release).